# postgresql not running in lucid ( 10.4 ) 64bit

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, postgresql, 64-bit

I installed postgresql through Ubuntu software center, but `ps -e|grep post` giving nothing.
and `sudo  /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4  start` gives nothing.
What may be wrong with me? I am using 64 bit 10.4.

Comment: have you checked the logs ?

Comment: grep postg syslog GIVES>> Jul 17 15:54:57 ofcnam-desktop AptDaemon: INFO: InstallPackages() was called: dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'postgresql')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))

Comment: checked all /var/log files nothing at the sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 start time.no files at /var/log/postgresql/

Comment: check /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to run `initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data` for the first time.
 oh my God... 
I wasted one full day to find this!!! what a shame.